# How to know "sales_order_place_after" event is captured in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I have done this so for:

**app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
<observer name="vendor_sales_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Extensoin\Observer\SendEmail" />
</event>
</config>
```

And at: **app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\SendEmail.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

class SendEmail implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
 $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
 echo $orderId = $order->getId();
 $comment = $this->getRequest()->getParam('comment');
 print_r("Catched event succssfully !"); exit;
}
}
```

But noting happens and I go to success page as usual. How to know event is captured or is there some other way to achieve it?

Comment: The observer class defined in your xml file does not match with your observer class name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems your observer class name is wrong `SendEmail`

your events.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_save_after">
        <observer name="mymodule_sales_order_save_after" instance="MyCompany\MyModule\Observer\Observer" />
    </event>
</config>
```

your observer file looks like

```
    <?php namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Observer; 
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface; 

    class Observer implements ObserverInterface { 

        protected $connector; public function __construct() { 
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
        }

        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) { 
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info('Catched event succssfully');

       }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @Hitesh, do confirm me is it event.xml or events.xml? secondly where the responce goes to show event is captured.. right now trying this answer it is still going to success page like in normal checkout process.

Comment: it's events.xml typo, did you try my code?

Comment: Let me try this again

Comment: Still same.. I tried echo "<pre>";
            print_r("Captured Successfuly"); exit;

Comment: echo exist will not work there I think to check my updated answer, try to log it

Comment: Yes getting this in templog.log "2018-11-30T06:35:34+00:00 INFO (6): Catched event succssfully
" I wanted to get Order can you tell how to by this way ?

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want to send order invoice in email to customer at the time, when he selects any of payment methods.